# Error that role of the previous master user does not exist when restoring a database to a different server with different master username

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, postgresql-11

I have to move a postgres database to another server. Both servers are Postgres 11.8 on Amazon RDS. I'm dumping the original `jira` database like this:

```
pg_dump \
  --dbname=postgresql://postgres:***@oldserver.***.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/jira \
  --file="$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M)"_jira \
  --format=d \
  --jobs=4 \
  --no-owner
```

The original `jira` database was running with the master user `postgres`, which has access to every database. I want this database to have it's own user with no access to any other database. Therefore on the new server I'm running this first:

```
PGPASSWORD=*** psql \
  --command="REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;" \
  --command="CREATE DATABASE jiradb;" \
  --command="REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE jiradb FROM PUBLIC;" \
  --command="CREATE USER jirauser WITH PASSWORD '***';" \
  --command="GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE jiradb TO jirauser;" \
  --dbname=postgres \
  --host=newserver.***.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com \
  --port=5432 \
  --username=testuser
```

This should ensure that the restored database runs with his own user `jirauser`. I'm restoring the dump like this:

```
PGPASSWORD=*** pg_restore \
  --dbname=jiradb \
  --host=newserver.***.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com \
  --jobs=4 \
  --no-owner \
  --port=5432 \
  --username=jirauser \
  --verbose \
  20201125_1405_jira
```

At the end of the restore I'm getting this error:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 8422; 0 0 ACL SCHEMA public postgres
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  role "postgres" does not exist
    Command was: REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM rdsadmin;
```

Should I be concerned about this? What I don't understand why it tries to revoke `rdsadmin` rights from the public schema? Shouldn't this just be a dump of my `jira` database without any `postgres` role or `rdsadmin` stuff?

I have tried with the `--data-only` option, but this just yields more errors.

What I understand is that it has something to do that the master user name being `postgres` on the old server and `testuser` on the new server. Should I also name the master user `postgres` on the new server?

@Laurenz Albe: When running `\du rdsadmin` I get:

```
postgres=> \du rdsadmin;
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 rdsadmin  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS+| {}
           | Password valid until infinity                              |
```

Comment: Strange error, but can probably be ignored. What do you get for `\du rdsadmin`?